# Services not deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

I am using MultipeerConnectivity and after app did enter in background, I stopped `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` and `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` instances and then nullify properties. And when app did become active create and start them again.

But after restart services I found self peer. When I run debug tool (allocations) I saw that `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` and `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` not released after I nullify them.

I am using ARC.

Comment: Having the same issue.  Also, have run into a long delay when setting the MCSession to nil.

Any updates on this?

Comment: @SteveM I am set nil to services delegates before nullify and thats all.

With MCSession I faced same problem. I am set session to nil after app did become active for re-create all services and session. For solved problem with delay I am create and replace old session in background queue.